# Filled cycle in TikZ with varying border styles

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have the following TikZ:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[fill=gray!50, dashed] 
([shift={(-0.5,0)}]0:0.5) arc[radius=0.5cm, start angle=0, end angle=45] 
-- ([shift={(0,0)}]102.5:0.383) arc[radius=0.383cm, start angle=102.5, end angle=67.5] 
-- ([shift={(0.5,0)}]135:0.5) arc[radius=0.5cm, start angle=135, end angle=180]  
-- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

It generates

[image: cusp]

I want this exact shape, except I want the arc that bounds the top to have a solid line instead of dashed. Can I do this in a single \draw command? If not, what's the easiest way to get this done?

Comment: Welcome! Please post a complete minimal example. That is much more useful than a mere fragment of code. But you cannot do this using a single `\draw`. Why is that important?

Comment: A compilable document starts with `\documentclass` and ends `\end{document}`.

Comment: Simplest probably is to draw over it with a solid arc in a subsequent draw command.

Comment: @PeterGrill thanks, you're probably right. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: Please use the official Stack Exchange interface for uploading images rather than self-hosting. This ensures that all images will always be accessible and won't expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is probably just to draw over it:

[image]

Note:

- I had to stretch the line by `0.18em` for some reason. Made the line width slightly larger to hide the slight discrepancy cause but this stretch. As you know the code better you can remove the `shorten <=-0.18em]` and `line width=0.57pt` options and adjust the drawing.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[fill=gray!50, dashed] 
   ([shift={(-0.5,0)}]0:0.5)    arc[radius=0.5cm,   start angle=0,     end angle=45  ] 
-- ([shift={(0,0)}]102.5:0.383) arc[radius=0.383cm, start angle=102.5, end angle=67.5] 
-- ([shift={(0.5,0)}]135:0.5)   arc[radius=0.5cm,   start angle=135,   end angle=180 ]  
-- cycle;

\draw [red, line width=0.57pt, cap=round, shorten <=-0.18em]  % 
    (102.5:0.383) arc[radius=0.383cm, start angle=102.5, end angle=67.5]
    ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) for comparison.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
path shape;
shape = buildcycle(halfcircle shifted 1/2 left, 
                   halfcircle scaled  3/4,
                   halfcircle shifted 1/2 right) scaled 3cm;

fill shape withcolor 3/4 white;
draw subpath(0,1) of shape dashed evenly;
draw subpath(2,4) of shape withcolor .67 red;
draw subpath(5,6) of shape dashed evenly;
endfig;
end.
```

I've used the `subpath (t,u) of p` notation where `t` and `u` represent the desired "time" along path `p`.

It can be a little tricky to figure out where MetaPost thinks the points are along a path that is created by `buildcycle`, but this case is typical in that there are two points at each corner.  To determine exactly which points I wanted, I used a temporary loop to label them all:

```
for i=1 upto length(shape): dotlabel.top(decimal i, point i of shape); endfor
```